# already defined in .obj & warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I know that many questions have been asked with the similar title. I have a class like this:

in CustomAllocator.h

```
namespace MemoryMgmt
  {   
  class MemoryManager
    {
      .....
    }
 }

class CustomAllocator
  {
  public:
    void * operator new(size_t i_size);
    void operator delete(void*, void*);
    virtual ~CustomAllocator(){}; 

#pragma warning(suppress: 4251)
    static boost::thread_specific_ptr< MemoryMgmt::MemoryManager> memory_manager_currentHA;
  };


// boost::thread_specific_ptr< MemoryMgmt::MemoryManager > CustomAllocator::memory_manager_currentHA;

inline void * CustomAllocator::operator new(size_t i_size)
  {
       if (!g_memory_manager_currentHA.get()) {
        memory_manager_currentHA.reset(new MemoryMgmt::MemoryManager);
       }
      return memory_manager_currentHA->AllocateChars(i_size);
  }
inline void CustomAllocator::operator delete(void * , void*)
  {
  //Should not be used
  ASSERT(!"Placement delete should not be used for memory objects");
  }
```

in CustomAllocator.cpp

```
#include <CustomAllocator.h>


MemoryMgmt::MemoryManager CustomAllocator::memory_manager_current = MemoryMgmt::MemoryManager();
boost::thread_specific_ptr< MemoryMgmt::MemoryManager > CustomAllocator::memory_manager_currentHA;
```

The header file calls in many different files. Of course there is a linking problem due to the declaration of the memory_manager_currentHA in the header file. However, when I declare it in cpp file there would be an other error:

**error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated**

I know that this error is due to the warning level that has been set for the (Level3 /W3) in visual studio C/C++ general configuration page.

I am wondering if there would be any solution to resolve this issue without changing the warning level.

**EDIT:**

For example one of the usage of the header file:

```
#include "CustomAllocator.h"
class MVeryLongData : public CustomAllocator
  {
    ....
  }
```

Comment: `#include <MemoryManager.h>` Where is your `#include "CustomAllocator.h"`? Post a [MCVE], as you should know by now you have to do...

Comment: I edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally resolved the issue by disabling locally the warnings.

```
#pragma warning (push)
#pragma warning(disable: 4100)
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#pragma warning(pop)

#pragma warning (push)
#pragma warning(disable: 4251)
    static boost::thread_specific_ptr< MemoryMgmt::MemoryManager> memory_manager_currentHA;
#pragma warning(pop)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should move the definition (storage) of `memory_manager_currentHA` to the .cpp file.

Comment: as I explained in the question, moving the definition results in different error. (warning level). what would be solution for resolving it?

Comment: He said he tried that. Since it's the right solution, the question does not contain enough information to answer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit what do you need more?

Comment: @H'H: For a start, remove the obviously wrong code and post the best version of the code you can in the question itself.   That is the one where HA is in the .cpp file.

Comment: @H'H: For a start, show us the version of the code that actually isn't working (as a [MCVE]) and the full error. There is no point showing your attempted solution that you already know is wrong.